# TYPO3 typoscript WHERE anotation, what is the difference?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In selecting specific content I collect only the elements from the column that has `colPos = 1`, I have two annotations that work for the where clause and I'd like to understand the difference;

```
10 = CONTENT
10 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList = this
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=1
        where = colPos = 1
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.stdWrap.field = header
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen the first variant. Maybe the select filters out some characters?

Comment: @ThomasLöffler - it was used in the bootstrap_package, introduced in TYPO3 V8 to ensure proper quoting as mathias answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version [ensures proper quoting for SQL field names](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/singlehtml/#important-80506-dbal-compatible-field-quoting-in-typoscript), the second version does not. This ensures compatibility with various DBMS. You should always use the first version if possible.

The annotation with the curly brackets has been introduced in TYPO3 V8.

Comment: spot_on mathias, thanx, if you add to your answer that this annotation is introduced in v8 I accept it !!